# Airmon-ng can't find Wlan0

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

When I run this command `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`. I have this :

```
Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!
-e 
PID Name
860 avahi-daemon
861 avahi-daemon
929 NetworkManager
946 wpa_supplicant
11627   dhclient
Process with PID 11627 (dhclient) is running on interface eth1


Interface   Chipset     Driver

eth1        Unknown     wl - [phy0]
```

I can't find Wlan0 to make it monitor : `mon0`

Answer (score 0):

Some useful information on wireless trouble shooting  [can be found here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide)

Although if you are trying to capture packets for analysis maybe use wireshark?

If you intend to use aircrack [( like here )](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=newbie_guide) or some variant then I'm not sure this forum is the best place for your question?

Also, to set a device to monitor mode I think this would need to be done.

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor
sudo iwconfig wlan0 up
```